# Change computer name in elementaryOS

Tags: release-juno

Can anyone tell me how to change the computer name in elementaryOS, please?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily rename your computer by editing the /etc/ hostname file.

In Terminal, type `sudo nano /etc/hostname`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, type your password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again. Delete the old name and type the new one. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save and then  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to close the editor. The new name will enter into effect after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

in terminal: `hostnamectl set-hostname new-hostname`

Comment: Your participation is much appreciated Let me inform you that we love informative answers with step by step guide. Please try to post detailed information. Have a nice day!